# NGINX and PHP-FPM is downloading index.php instead of processing it

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, fastcgi

php-fpm is running:

```
# /etc/init.d/php5-fpm status
php5-fpm is running
```

php-fpm is listening:

```
# netstat -an | grep :9000
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

Nginx config in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:

```
# Nginx web server main configuration file: /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
#
user www-data;
worker_processes  8;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
  multi_accept on;
}

http {
  default_type application/octet-stream;
  gzip on;
  gzip_disable "msie6";
  keepalive_timeout 65;
  sendfile on;
  tcp_nodelay on;
  tcp_nopush on;
  types_hash_max_size 8192;
  include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
  include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;
}
```

The second config is a shortcut in /etc/nginx/conf.d:

```
# Aegir web server main configuration file

#######################################################
###  nginx.conf main
#######################################################

 ## FastCGI params
 ## fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME     $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
  fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME     $document_root;
  fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING        $query_string;
  fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD      $request_method;
  fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE        $content_type;
  fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH      $content_length;
  fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME         $fastcgi_script_name;
  fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI         $request_uri;
  fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI        $document_uri;
  fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT       $document_root;
  fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL     $server_protocol;
  fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE   CGI/1.1;
  fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE     ApacheSolaris/$nginx_version;
  fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR         $remote_addr;
  fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT         $remote_port;
  fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR         $server_addr;
  fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT         $server_port;
  fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME         $server_name;
  fastcgi_param  USER_DEVICE         $device;
  fastcgi_param  GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE  $geoip_country_code;
  fastcgi_param  GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE3 $geoip_country_code3;
  fastcgi_param  GEOIP_COUNTRY_NAME  $geoip_country_name;
  fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS     200;
  fastcgi_index  index.php;

 ## Default index files
  index         index.php index.html;

 ## Size Limits
  client_body_buffer_size        64k;
  client_header_buffer_size      32k;
  client_max_body_size          100m;
  large_client_header_buffers 32 32k;
  connection_pool_size           256;
  request_pool_size               4k;
  server_names_hash_bucket_size  512;
  server_names_hash_max_size    8192;
  types_hash_bucket_size         512;
  map_hash_bucket_size           192;
  fastcgi_buffer_size           128k;
  fastcgi_buffers             256 4k;
  fastcgi_busy_buffers_size     256k;
  fastcgi_temp_file_write_size  256k;

 ## Timeouts
  client_body_timeout             60;
  client_header_timeout           60;
  send_timeout                    60;
  lingering_time                  30;
  lingering_timeout                5;
  fastcgi_connect_timeout         60;
  fastcgi_send_timeout           300;
  fastcgi_read_timeout           300;

 ## Open File Performance
  open_file_cache max=8000 inactive=30s;
  open_file_cache_valid          60s;
  open_file_cache_min_uses         3;
  open_file_cache_errors          on;

 ## FastCGI Caching
  fastcgi_cache_path /var/lib/nginx/speed
                     levels=2:2:2
                     keys_zone=speed:10m
                     inactive=15m
                     max_size=3g;

 ## General Options
  ignore_invalid_headers          on;
  limit_conn_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=gulag:10m;
  recursive_error_pages           on;
  reset_timedout_connection       on;
  fastcgi_intercept_errors        on;
  server_tokens                  off;
  fastcgi_hide_header         'Link';
  fastcgi_hide_header  'X-Generator';
  fastcgi_hide_header 'X-Powered-By';
  fastcgi_hide_header 'X-Drupal-Cache';

 ## TCP options moved to /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

 ## SSL performance
  ssl_session_cache   shared:SSL:10m;
  ssl_session_timeout            10m;

 ## GeoIP support
  geoip_country /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoIP.dat;

 ## Compression
  gzip_buffers      16 8k;
  gzip_comp_level   5;
  gzip_http_version 1.0;
  gzip_min_length   10;
  gzip_types        text/plain text/css application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
  gzip_vary         on;
  gzip_proxied      any;
  add_header Vary "Accept-Encoding";
  gzip_static       on;
  upload_progress uploads 1m;

 ## Log Format
  log_format        main '"$proxy_add_x_forwarded_for" $host [$time_local] '
                         '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
                         '$request_length $bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                         '"$http_user_agent" $request_time "$gzip_ratio"';

  client_body_temp_path  /var/lib/nginx/body 1 2;
  access_log             /var/log/nginx/access.log main buffer=32k;
  error_log              /var/log/nginx/error.log crit;

# Extra configuration from modules:
#######################################################
###  nginx default maps
#######################################################

###
### Support separate Boost and Speed Booster caches for various mobile devices.
###
map $http_user_agent $device {
  default                                                                normal;
  ~*Nokia|BlackBerry.+MIDP|240x|320x|Palm|NetFront|Symbian|SonyEricsson  mobile-other;
  ~*iPhone|iPod|Android|BlackBerry.+AppleWebKit                          mobile-smart;
  ~*iPad|Tablet                                                          mobile-tablet;
}

###
### Set a cache_uid variable for authenticated users (by @brianmercer and @perusio, fixed by @omega8cc).
###
map $http_cookie $cache_uid {
  default  '';
  ~SESS[[:alnum:]]+=(?<session_id>[[:graph:]]+)  $session_id;
}

###
### Live switch of $key_uri for Speed Booster cache depending on $args.
###
map $request_uri $key_uri {
  default                                                                            $request_uri;
  ~(?<no_args_uri>[[:graph:]]+)\?(.*)(utm_|__utm|_campaign|gclid|source=|adv=|req=)  $no_args_uri;
}

###
### Set cache expiration depending on the Drupal core version.
###
map $sent_http_x_purge_level $will_expire_in {
  default   on-demand;
  ~*5|none  5m;
}

###
### Deny crawlers.
###
map $http_user_agent $is_crawler {
  default  '';
  ~*HTTrack|BrokenLinkCheck|2009042316.*Firefox.*3\.0\.10|MJ12|HTMLParser|libwww|PECL|Automatic|Click|SiteBot|BuzzTrack|Sistrix|Offline|Screaming|Nutch|Mireo|SWEB|Morfeus|GSLFbot  is_crawler;
}

###
### Deny all known bots on some URIs.
###
map $http_user_agent $is_bot {
  default  '';
  ~*crawl|goog|yahoo|yandex|spider|bot|tracker|click|parser  is_bot;
}

###
### Deny almost all crawlers under high load.
###
map $http_user_agent $deny_on_high_load {
  default  '';
  ~*crawl|goog|yahoo|yandex|baidu|bing|spider|tracker|click|parser  deny_on_high_load;
}

###
### Deny listed requests for security reasons.
###
map $args $is_denied {
  default  '';
  ~*delete.+from|insert.+into|select.+from|union.+select|onload|\.php.+src|system\(.+|document\.cookie|\;|\.\.  is_denied;
}

#######################################################
###  nginx default server
#######################################################

server {
  limit_conn   gulag 32; # like mod_evasive - this allows max 32 simultaneous connections from one IP address
  listen       *:80;
  server_name  _;
  location / {
     root   /var/www/nginx-default;
     index  index.html index.htm;
  }
}

#######################################################
###  nginx virtual domains
#######################################################

# virtual hosts
include /var/aegir/config/server_master/nginx/pre.d/*;
include /var/aegir/config/server_master/nginx/platform.d/*;
include /var/aegir/config/server_master/nginx/vhost.d/*;
include /var/aegir/config/server_master/nginx/post.d/*;
```

And my last config I added is located in /etc/nginx/conf.d/. Not a shortcut.

```
server {
listen   80; 


root /var/www/nginx-default/cacti;
index index.php index.html index.htm;


location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}

location /doc/ {
    alias /usr/share/doc/;
    autoindex on;
    allow 127.0.0.1;
    allow ::1;
    deny all;
}

error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
location = /50x.html {
    root /var/www/nginx-default/cacti;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;

    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;

    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
}

location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

These two lines here look rather odd.

```
## fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME     $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME     $document_root;
```

I believe the first should be uncommented and the second commented.

If it's still downloading the file after that, you should check the download to see if it has been processed or if it is source code. If it has been processed, you may need to change the mime-type in the php block.